# Filtering json-map objects by fields value, which is Some(value)

Tags: json, scala, types, scala-collections

There is a json file with more than 10000 rows. You can see the data format below:

```
{"id":1,"child_id":1822925634,"parent_id":-1,"name":"victor"}
{"id":2,"child_id":1266710134,"parent_id":25,"name":"victor"}
{"id":3,"child_id":572534000,"parent_id":-1,"name":"simone"}
.
.
.
{"id":10575,"child_id":572534781,"parent_id":135,"name":"victor"}
```

I want to filter all rows with **parent_id** equal to **-1**.

First, my code reads file content, and then split it by line breaks.

```
val file = new File("./myFile.json")
val jsonContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file)
JSON.globalNumberParser = {input : String => Integer.parseInt(input)}
val jsonArray = jsonContent.split("\n").map(x=>JSON.parseFull(x).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]])
```

So far, I have a map object with 4 key-value pairs (everything is OK up to here). To debug a little bit, **temp** returns **"Some(-1)"** as expected.

```
val temp = jsonArray(2).get("parent_id")
```

Now, I want to filter **jsonArray** based on **parent_id**

```
val selectedRows = jsonArray.filter(_.get("parent_id")=="-1").map(_.get("name"))
```

But it returns an empty map object. The problem is the equation is not satisfied. I tried ("parent_id")==*"-1"* or *"Some(-1)"* or *Some("-1")*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map.get` returns an `Option` and therefore your expression `_.get("parent_id")=="-1"` is always `false`.

You need to convert it to `_.get("parent_id") == Some(-1)`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect to get an integer value there